# Root shell sees pip but sudo pip "command not found"

Tags: shell, sudo, command-not-found

I have installed python 2.7.8 via `make` and `make install` and then pip via [get-pip](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html). I have to note that I work behind a proxy which I have set up via

- `http_proxy`
- `ftp_proxy`
- `https_proxy`

in

- my user's `~/.zshrc`
- root's `/root/.basrc`

now I am able to run `pip`

- on my user account
- on root account

but I am not able to run it via my user's shell using sudo

```
sudo pip
sudo: pip: command not found
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That'll be because the [`PATH` is different when running with `sudo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why). Try comparing:

```
which pip
env
```

vs.

```
sudo which pip
sudo env
```

One secure workaround is to create a symbolic link to `pip` in [`/usr/local/bin`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308045/differences-between-bin-sbin-usr-bin-usr-sbin-usr-local-bin-usr-local) or even `/usr/bin`. If you install `pip` using a package manager it will do this automatically on several (most?) distros.

Comment: thanks, `alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'` solved the issue.

Comment: There are security issues with that - you don't want to blindly set this in all your environments!

Comment: I'm not sure if it was super clear in this answer, but the solution is indeed a `ln -s /usr/local/bin/<stuff> /usr/bin/<stuff>`